# jQuery: using variable in animate for left continuous update

Tags: jquery

```
var shiftLeft = -250;
setInterval(function(){
 $("UL")animate( { left: '-=250' }, 500);
}, 2000);
```

Here, in above code code I need `shiftLeft` variable to be used in `animate` function instead of `-=250`.

Comment: Does `shiftLeft` really needs to be integer, or can you make it a string?

Comment: Also, you need dot in front of animate - `.animate` but I guess it's a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var shiftLeft = -250;
var shiftLeftStr = shiftLeft.toString();
var a = shiftLeftStr.substr(0, 1);
var b = shiftLeftStr.substr(1);
var animatePx = a + "=" + b;
setInterval(function(){
 $("UL").animate( { left: animatePx }, 500);
}, 2000);
```

So, first you make it a string. After that you use `substr` to get first char, and after that remaining chars.

And after all, you put all those pieces together.

Comment: Well I was expecting direct usage of variable with little tweak if any. I would make a function for this and use it.